# It is forbidden to climb Gangkhar Puensum, but what's really stopping anyone?

Tags: legal, mountain-climbing, bhutan

In Bhutan, it is illegal to climb any mountain higher than 6000m, but what is stopping anyone from doing it anyway, and how likely is it that you would be found out?

I cannot imagine it is feasible to protect the mountains with a fence, or guards, and a person would be nearly impossible to spot on a mountain at a distance, so what is the mechanism for enforcement of this law?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we don't give advice or support in breaking laws or regulations

Comment: @Hilmar I'm not condoning breaking any laws, only merely a conversation point about how this law is actually enforced.

Comment: A short trip up a 6000m mountain??  Even if it's a walk-up mountain like Kilimanjaro 6000m requires acclimatization.  You're just going to disappear for some days to do it?

Comment: WP has information that I felt like I needed after reading the question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gangkhar_Puensum The prohibition is religious. The mountain lies near the border between Tibet (Chinese control) and Bhutan. The summit is believed to be inside Bhutan. A 1998 attempt to climb it from the Chinese side had its permission withdrawn by the Chinese authorities because of the political issues.

Comment: Given the difficulty of climbing a 6,000m mountain and the fact that nobody is likely to provide a step-by-step guide to evading the authorities here, this seems more like a question about how the law works than a question about advice on how to break the law. Similarly, we have questions about how ticket inspections work on transit systems, but wouldn't permit a guide to jumping turnstiles.

Comment: I guess just like any crime, you might be safe as long as nobody noticed it, but [became *in*famous if you got caught](https://www.quora.com/When-I-m-older-I-am-determined-to-climb-Mt-Gangkhar-Puensum-but-mountaineering-is-forbidden-in-that-country-so-what-will-happen-to-me-if-I-climbed-it-without-any-permission)

Comment: In most places, it is illegal to murder people. How is that enforced? What is really stopping anyone?

Comment: Laws are based on the notion of prosecuting _after_ the fact rather than physically stopping you from breaking the law. In your case, a pair of binoculars and patience for you to climb down is all that is needed in terms of law enforcement.

Comment: A person on a mountainside is actually very easy to spot.  Above treeline there's not much cover, and hiking/climbing clothes and gear are usually brightly colored for safety.  Red and orange clothes and tents show up very nicely against a background of brown rocks and white snow, and as Sanchises says, rangers certainly have binoculars.  Unless you're going to dress in camouflage, but then good luck getting found if you need to be rescued.

Comment: @LorenPechtel It is completely feasible to make a short trip to a walkable 6000 mountain when doing trekking around 5000 m (I did it on a casual trek in Ladakh). However, the very mountain in question is a hard climbing 7500 and that is a completely different matter.

Comment: @NateEldredge Getting found?  In the era of PLBs that's not much of an issue.

Comment: @Sanchises I mean the question "How are speed limits enforced?" could get answers from "There are patrol cars" or "cameras" or "planes"

Comment: This wasn't supposed to be such a controversial question. This was the result of a conversation over Christmas dinner. I am not planning to go to Bhutan and attempt to climb any of the mountains - I struggle to get up my own stairs. Perhaps I could have been a bit more careful with my wording.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Climbing Uluru / Ayers Rock in Australia is culturally insensitive, and has been completely banned since 2019.  I'd bet it still happens though.

Comment: @Criggie Right, and some people still do murders. Most don't, though, and the answer to "why" is also the answer to this question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't have any specific insights into how it's enforced on the ground but it doesn't seem particularly difficult.

You cannot climb a mountain like that in a few hours or on your own. Even assuming you're a specialist and don't want to rely on local help (i.e. you're eshewing the “expedition style” climbing that's typical of the Himalayas), you would need special equipment, which can easily be detected at the border or somewhere on the way.

As most mountains in the Himalayas are relatively remote, even the approach might be challenging. Again, unless you are being very deliberate about it (think special operation forces), you cannot travel places like that without assistance or interaction with the locals, so many opportunities for people to wonder what you are trying to do and either report you or get involved themselves.

That's especially true in Bhutan as it sees relatively few tourists (deliberately so) and requires them to book their trip through an approved tour operator. You cannot just show up there and hope to hide in a huge crowd.

Comment: It should also be noted that all foreigners except for Indian citizens are required to travel with a tour guide present. So you'd need to somehow escape your tour guide or bribe them first, which is a challenge on its own.

Comment: Or have an Indian passport...

Comment: Or be a Bhutan native yourself.

Comment: @Sebastian Citizenship is ok. It will accept other form of IDs also to get in. Passport not mandatory.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the good answer you already have it's worth noting than climbing of all kinds had a very strong sense of ethics. This covers sporting integrity, environmental impact and cultural sensitivity, plus safety of course. 6000m+ mountaineering is also a pretty niche pursuit with a small community and you'd be unlikely to get to this level without first being at least somewhat known by that community. These factors together mean that to some extent these things are self policing. Of course there are always exceptions, so I'm sure it would be possible with very careful planning, but you wouldn't win much praise for it.

Comment: Depends on which 6000 m +, there are many non-technical peaks of such altitude that an average tourist/trekker/non-technical-mountaineer can walk up.

Comment: There is also the ethical issue of rescue if things go wrong. One of the most unethical things you can do in mountaineering is to unnecessarily put rescuers at risk. Going on some kind of illegal stealth climb complicates rescue if you need it. And in a third-world country, the resources available to rescuers are skimpy.